# Increase pauses in an audio (a dialog)

Tags: audio, repeater, sound-editing, pause

I am a language learner and I have a few audio files, mostly dialogues.

I look for a ways to

a) add/extend pauses between sentences, or between different actors, whichever is easier

b) if possible, repeat sentences after the pause.

This would let me repeat the sentence during the
extended pause and, ideally, double check did I miss any details

While I post only to this forum due to rules against cross-posting,  but solution using cell phone, or a script/snipped in your scripting language of choice, whatever is worth considering.

I would prefer an automatic solution as I have several records, and free as in 'free beer' solution.

There are a lot tutorials of auto-removing pauses but I did not find anything on inserting or extending pauses or repeating a sentence twice.

Thanks

One obvious manual solution to pause extending could be use windows (or whatever OS) player and recorder app, say on desktop and laptop/mobile, and adding pauses manually. I tried the Audiomass sound editor. There is a button or tool to insert space, but looks like a lot of clicking required.